# What is the appropriate preposition for spot?

Tags: prepositions

> 1. The first member is standing up at the first spot.
> 2. The first member is standing up on the first spot.

Which preposition is appropriate?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! "At" and "on" are not articles but prepositions.

Comment: Do you mean which preposition?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by **first spot**. In the context of a "multi-artist" entertainment show, for example, it's *The support band are **in/on** [for] the first spot* (or *first **slot***). Also, who is the "member", and why is he "first"? (is he only first *because* he's on the first spot, or is he something like *[First Minister of Wales?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Minister_of_Wales)*

Comment: As far as I know, the phrase "at the spot" means "a particular space or area". I would use "at the first spot".

Answer (score 3):

*At* is used with places.  If the "spot" can be considered a place, *at* can be used.

*X on Y* is used if

- Y is a flat surface or object and
- The feet or bottom part of X makes contact with the surface, or top surface of that object.

If the "spot" fulfills that criteria, *on* can be used.

It's possible both *on* or *at* will work and in that case it doesn't matter which you use.